# Can't access phpmyadmin (403 permission error)

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpMyAdmin on my Virtual Private Server, but I can't access it from my browser to set it up.
I verified that the folder permissions on /phpmyadmin are the same as my public_html folder.

When I go to url (http://www.testsite.com/phpmyadmin) I get a 403 error
"You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server. Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.testsite.com Port 80"

I then go to my /var/log/httpd/error.log and see an entry for the denied access (note I partially replaced my IP address with x's)
[Thu Oct 29 19:12:46 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.68.18] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

I then edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf  which has the following lines

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

In each section of code listed above, I add just below Allow from ::1

```
Allow from xx.xxx.68.18
```

I'm still getting the same 403 error. I would appreciate some insights and direction to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed phpMyAdmin in your linux server (centos/RHEL/debian), and tried to access phpMyAdmin in most cases you will get this 403 forbidden error. I have seen this issue very often if you are installing phpmyadmin using yum or by apt-get. By default phpmyadmin installed path is **/usr/share/phpmyadmin** and the apache configuration file is located in /**etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf**.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access **/phpmyadmin/** on this server.

To fix:

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Remove or comment the first two lines in below.

> ```
> #Order Allow,Deny
> #Deny from all
> ```

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Restart the apache server.

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue with a new install of Fedora 25, Apache, MariaDB and PHP.

The router is on 192.168.1.1 and the Fedora 25 server is sitting at 192.168.1.100 which is a staic address handed out by the router. The laptop was getting a random ip in the range of 192.168.1.101 to 150.

The change I made to the /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf was instances of

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.1/24
```

This worked for me. The idea came from the process of inserting the ip address of the laptop into the .conf file behind the reference to 127.0.0.1 and I was able to get access.

So instead of doing the more secure thing of handing out a static ip address to the laptop I let the phpMyAdmin.conf file open to a range of ip address on the local subnet, if that is the right terminology.

If there are drawbacks to doing this let me know so that I can make the appropriate changes.

Comment: If someone installed phpmyadmin over the `rh-php70-php-fpm` and was able to log in pma but the image were broken, this solution fixed the problem for me. (also have to install `rh-php70-php-mbstring rh-php70-php-mysqli` if pma conplain about mbstring)